# BLUE estimators

Tags: regression, machine-learning, generalized-linear-model

I am studying BLUE estimators( Best linear unbiased estimates) in my stats course and I have understood until the derivation of B hat(regression coefficient estimate in y=Bx+error). Now my notes are saying that as B hat is not unique and may be unbiased we consider lambda*beta hat instead and define the following: [image: Gauss Markov Theorem]

It then somehow manages to show that this is the estimate with the least variance. I do not understand why lamba must be involved at all and not just b hat. b hat to me seams like the reasonable estimate given the data and not some multiple of it. Please explain why this is done.

The reasoning for lambda: [image: Lambda reasoning]

Let me know if you need anything else.

Answer (score 1):

2 problems have problem in themselves.

1. "In general" should not appear in the statistical writing, Should point out under what condition, the estimate is unique and under what condition it is not.

The correct answer should be: If $X$ is full column rank matrix, the estimate of $\beta$ is unique, otherwise, not unique.

2. "may not be" implies "may be". So this sentence does not tell reader anything. When the estimate of $\beta$ is unique, the estimate is unbiased. When not unique, how to define (un)bias? Same as in problem 1, the conditions that estimate is biased and unbiased should be listed.

That $\lambda$ is method to add the conditions to $X$, such that $X$ is full column rank matrix under the restrictions. Therefore, the estimate of $\beta$ will be unique.

Comment: How does this solve the problem? Why is X being full rank so important? Is there a formal name for this so I can look this up?

Comment: If $X$ is not full rank, then $(X'X)^{-1}$ does not exist, so we need to use $(X'X)^-$ toget $\hat \beta$, which is not unique. One example is: create two dummy variable for gender, one for male, and one for female. Intercept and two dummy variables create less-than full-rank design matrix $X$. The simple method to resolve this problem is drop the columns form $X$. In the gender example, dropping any 1 column will resolve the problem. Any MATHEMATICAL statistical textbook on general linear model has the detail description about this issue.